# How can I add limits in the fraction?

Tags: amsmath, fractions

I can't seem to add limits in fractions. I tried `\[ \frac{\lim_ {x \to a}[f(x)]} {{\lim_ {x \to a} [g(x)]}} \]`

But it just doesn't want to do it. Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No problem with these codes:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}


     \[ \frac{\lim_ {x \to a}f(x)} {\lim_ {x \to a} g(x)}\qquad \frac{\lim\limits_ {x \to a}f(x)} {\lim\limits_ {x \to a} g(x)} \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]